# I need a simple barcode scanner, that can save the barodes value in a variable

Tags: python, barcode

I want to use my computers webcam as a barcode scanner. So when i run a program my computer will take a picture, analyse the barcode and save the value of the barcode in a variable. But i have no idea how to do this. I know a little about cv2, and i've been reading about zbar, but i can't find anything with a simple solution to my problem. I have no idea how to even start coding, so i'm gonna ask if somebody's got some code they want to share for my help.

I'm novice, so i have no idea how to approach this. I know it's possible, but i can't finde anything simple. I found this program; https://www.codepool.biz/python-pyqt-read-barcode-webcam.html
but it's way too fancy and i dont need the UI.

None

None

Comment: The code is short enough. Just remove all the Qt-UI stuff and keep just the openCV-barcode-reading stuff.

Comment: This site is meant to help with specific code problems where the asker has already attempted and researched the problem, provides the full code and errors necessary to reproduce and understand and then help by fixing bugs in the code. It is not meant for people to just ask others to do the coding for them because the asker doesn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

@Kasper,

If you are running Windows, we have a built in decoder that enables reading barcodes through a standard "auto-focus" camera.  See https://aka.ms/camerabarcode for documentation and sample code.  We also have a sample app that uses this implementation available in the Windows Store -- See https://aka.ms/justscanit.

Terry Warwick, Microsoft